# React Native Background Timer with QR-code

Tags: android, ios, react-native, qr-code

I wanted to create an application when pointing at the qr code, the timer started in background mode, and stopped when scanning again. That is, so that the timer works in the background without stopping until the qr code is scanned again.
This code of qr scanner:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button,Alert } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';



export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
  }

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />
      {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: What do you need to do with the timer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library [React Native Background Timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer) which might give what you want.

You can start timer by calling following function inside your `handleBarCodeScanned`

```
BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer(); //to stop previous background timer

BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => { 
   //write code here that will be called every seconds 
}, 
1000);
```